# ktLintFormat fails with an error: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' (macOS w/ Apple M1 chip)

Tags: android, ktlint

Installed `ktLint` on my Android Studio project but when running I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.KtlintCommandLine.parallel(Main.kt:576)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.KtlintCommandLine.parallel$default(Main.kt:548)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.KtlintCommandLine.lintFiles(Main.kt:298)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.KtlintCommandLine.run(Main.kt:262)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.Main.main(Main.kt:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.exception.FrequentErrorLogger.report(FrequentErrorLogger.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.exception.FrequentErrorLogger.info(FrequentErrorLogger.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.handleUnspecifiedTrace(DebugUtil.java:626)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.currentInvalidationTrace(DebugUtil.java:618)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.calcInvalidationTrace(DebugUtil.java:612)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.onInvalidated(DebugUtil.java:583)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.TreeElement.onInvalidated(TreeElement.java:226)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.TreeElement.rawRemoveUpToWithoutNotifications(TreeElement.java:388)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.TreeElement.rawRemoveUpTo(TreeElement.java:342)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.remove(CompositeElement.java:775)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.lambda$removeChildrenInner$4(CompositeElement.java:797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.ChangeUtil$1.runInner(ChangeUtil.java:149)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.pom.impl.PomTransactionBase.run(PomTransactionBase.java:46)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.internal.FormatPomModel.runTransaction(KotlinPsiFileFactory.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.ChangeUtil.prepareAndRunChangeAction(ChangeUtil.java:143)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.removeChildrenInner(CompositeElement.java:796)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositeElement.replaceChild(CompositeElement.java:623)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeEditUtil.replaceChild(CodeEditUtil.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.extapi.psi.ASTDelegatePsiElement.replaceChildInternal(ASTDelegatePsiElement.java:385)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.extapi.psi.ASTDelegatePsiElement.replace(ASTDelegatePsiElement.java:375)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtExpressionImplStub.rawReplace(KtExpressionImplStub.java:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtExpressionImpl$Companion.replaceExpression(KtExpressionImpl.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtExpressionImplStub.replace(KtExpressionImplStub.java:43)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.ruleset.standard.StringTemplateRule.visit(StringTemplateRule.kt:49)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.KtLint$format$1.invoke(KtLint.kt:389)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.KtLint$format$1.invoke(KtLint.kt:382)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.KtLint$visitor$2$2.invoke(KtLint.kt:313)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.KtLint$visitor$2$2.invoke(KtLint.kt:312)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:229)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.ast.PackageKt.visit(package.kt:230)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.KtLint$visitor$2.invoke(KtLint.kt:312)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.KtLint$visitor$2.invoke(KtLint.kt:300)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.core.KtLint.format(KtLint.kt:382)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.internal.FileUtilsKt.formatFile(FileUtils.kt:202)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.KtlintCommandLine.process(Main.kt:366)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.KtlintCommandLine.access$process(Main.kt:89)
    at com.pinterest.ktlint.KtlintCommandLine$lintFiles$3.invoke$lambda-0(Main.kt:289)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient java.lang.Object java.lang.Throwable.backtrace accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @fe48b45
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.findFieldInHierarchy(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredField(ReflectionUtil.java:278)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ThrowableInterner.<clinit>(ThrowableInterner.java:81)
    ... 50 more

> Task :app:ktlintFormat FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:ktlintFormat'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I'v found some places talking about a wrong version of Java installed to satisfy ktLint, but it's from last year and I'mm already using a newer version of Java the what was suggested. F.eks. this thread:
https://githubmemory.com/repo/pinterest/ktlint/issues/1227

Here is my `ktLint.gradle` file which is quite standard:

```
configurations {
    ktlint
}

dependencies {
    ktlint "com.pinterest:ktlint:0.43.2"
}

task ktlint(type: JavaExec, group: "verification") {
    description = "Check Kotlin code style."
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
    ignoreExitValue = true
    // create html report for CI and plain report for terminal report
    args "--android", "--color", "--reporter=plain", "--reporter=checkstyle,output=${buildDir}/reports/ktlint-results.xml", "src/**/*.kt"
}

task ktlintFormat(type: JavaExec, group: "formatting") {
    description = "Fix Kotlin code style deviations."
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
    args  "-F", "src/**/*.kt"
    jvmArgs("--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED")
}
```

**And the Java version:**

```
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Hardware:**

```
macOS Monterey 12.0.1
Apple M1 chip
```

**Gradle** 7.3.3

Answer (score 2):

Configure your `ktlintFormat` task to include `jvmArgs("--add-opens", "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED")`, works for me with with JDK 17.0.1.

Source: https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/1195

Comment: Thanks man, was really thrilled to get your answer as the problem persisted. Added the extra jvmArgs. It runs through the code, corrects what needs corrected, leaves comments on being unable to fix Wildcards (why is that?), but ends with the same error again. Quite annoying already: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:ktlintFormat'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
`

Comment: Upgraded to Gradle 7 and still get the same error.

Comment: try latest ktlint `0.43.2` and Gradle `7.3.3`, are you still getting `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`?

Comment: Yes, just upgraded from 7.0.2 to 7.3.3 using ktLint 0.43.2 and the result is the same. It does it's thing, namely corrects what needs corrected, warns about wildcards, and then ends with the error: `> Task :app:ktlintFormat FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:ktlintFormat'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
`